# Issue in location.href in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**I have below code**

```
{!! Form::button('Cancel', array('class' => "btn btn-primary", 
                       'onclick' => "location.href = URL::asset('/departments');"))!!}
```

**This produces below URL:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = URL::asset('/departments');" 
                                                             type="button">Cancel</button>
```

Can you please suggest the correct way to add path in `onclick` function ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, after you had accepted, please check it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
{!! Form::button('Cancel', array('class' => "btn btn-primary", 
                       'onclick' => "location.href = ".url('/departments')))!!}
```

Just as a side node, /departments is not an asset but route.

Side note 2: You do not need Form at all for a cancel button, just some HTML.

```
<a href="{{url('departments')}}" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: Don't wrap `button` with `a`. Do `<a href="{{ url() }}" class="btn btn-primary"></a>` instead. It'll provide the same visual output.